# Boostrap 3 on Heroku doesn't show up

Tags: ruby, git, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Well I'm deploying on Heroku for the first time, thus this might come a bit rustic, but the issue at hand is pretty annoying.
I added my project filed to git and pushed it to Heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

However it doesn't seem to read my CSS which used bootstrap 3. I went through some documentation and added this gem to my Gemfile, in the production group and ran bundle install.

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

I uploaded the contents again and still nothing. What am I missing? The site and all its assests are working fine locally.

Comment: try by giving direct link to bootstrap cdn. ie `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Will linking to a CDN precompile the code in the asset pipeline. I'm using the bootstrap gem in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding these two gems to my application

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
  gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
end
```

Ran bundle install and then pushed to heroku. The pages started loading the CSS. Though have to admit that I don't exactly understand what's happening behind the scenes.